# Lookup or index/match for two combined data validation drop-downs

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I have a data validation dropdown in B13 and another in F13. Depending on the combined selections I want to copy a corresponding two rates rate from another tab and put one in B23 and the other in D23. For example, if from the first dropdown they select Carefirst PPO and in the second dropdown they choose Employee/Retiree + 1 then the employer portion of the rate goes in B23 and the employees go in D23 from a rate sheet in another tab.

If it’s the best way, I would like to do a lookup or index/match for two combined data validation drop-downs

If it helps, each plan type has a code so Carefirst PPO for Employee/Retiree + 1 is M011. There are five plans and 10 employee types per plan. I was hoping I could do some data validation/lookup etc.

[Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1as5D8t0FR5vPSck06Ta_HOb3225h_qTz/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=117177585904979702298&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: As player0 mentioned, please share a copy or sample of your spreadsheet (remove sensitive data if any). You are most likely to get help if you provide a minimal reproducible example we can replicate and experiment on :https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1as5D8t0FR5vPSck06Ta_HOb3225h_qTz/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=117177585904979702298&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: This is also possible via apps script. I can provide you with app script code, would you prefer that instead? However we would need to save it as Google Sheets format (.GSHEET) not as excel (.XLSX), hope that's not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can set dynamic query using **Named Ranges**.

1. First set the tables for each health insurances carrier as a named range:

   - From the menu above select **Data** -> **Named Ranges**
   - Set the name *exactly* as the options in the Data Validation (B13) > Highlight the range of the data.

   Do this for every selection on your dropdown. I have included column G so you can also refer to it on cell D23.

[image]

You should end up with all the options as your named ranges[image]

2. Enter this formula on cell B23. `=QUERY(indirect($B$13),"select E where B= '"&$F$13&"' ")`. For cell D23, just change the "select E" to "select G" to return the value from column G.

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Note in my example I have changed the rates to see if the data changes. I have also applied these changes and formula to the spreadsheet link you've shared so you can see it working.

- [Named Ranges](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/63175?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop)